# json動的生成とアクセス方法について

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

DBから任意の値を取得して、jsonを動的に生成した後の定数？にアクセスする方法がわかりません。
どなたかヒント等いただけますでしょうか
下記のような実装を考えています。

例えばですが

```
（JQuery）

　　　var json_data = <?php echo $json ?>; // php等でJSONの値を取得
　　　var json = JSON.parse(json_data);　　// JSONのデコード
　　　for( value in list ){ 　　　　　　　  // JSONの個数分ループ（3つの場合3回）
         var index = 0; 
         if('〇' == json.index){         // 問題点：アクセスしたいのは現在のループ回数
             console.log(true);
         }
      }

      JOSN想定
      { 〇, ×, 〇}　//1回目
      { 〇, ×, ×, ×}　//2回目（別データ）
      { 〇, ×, 〇, ×, ×, 〇} //3回目（別データ）
```

JSONデータは動的に個数は変更されます。実際に入る値としては「6種類」想定です。
ループはJSONと同じ数分しか行わないので
「index」の最大値はJSONの個数と同じになります。

つたない質問で申し訳ないですが、回答よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

この質問内容だと、要するに「回数」という状態をwebブラウザ側(Jquery側)で持ちたいという質問に見えます。

ブラウザは通常、状態は持ちえない(原理上リロードされかねないので)ので、そういう場合は、[Web Storage](http://www.htmq.com/webstorage/)などを使うのが一般的だと思います。